# Binding number keys to buttons for calculator

Tags: python, tkinter, key-bindings

How do I go on about doing this? I don't like the the idea of having to press each individual button. I'm really trying to understand all of this. I get the concept of binding I just don't know how to do it.

```
from tkinter import *


class Calc():
    def __init__(self):
        self.total = 0
        self.current = ""
        self.new_num = True
        self.op_pending = False
        self.op = ""
        self.eq_flag = False

    def num_press(self, num):
        temp = text_box.get()
        self.eq_flag = False
        temp2 = str(num)      
        if self.new_num == True:
            self.current = temp2
            self.new_num = False
        else:
            if temp2 == '.':
                if temp2 in temp:
                    return
            self.current = temp + temp2
        text_box.delete(0, END)
        text_box.insert(0, self.current)

    def calc_total(self):
        if self.op_pending == True:
            self.do_sum()
            self.op_pending = False

    def do_sum(self):
        self.current = float(self.current)
        if self.op == "add":
            self.total += self.current
        if self.op == "minus":
            self.total -= self.current
        if self.op == "times":
            self.total *= self.current
        if self.op == "divide":
            self.total /= self.current
        text_box.delete(0, END)
        text_box.insert(0, self.total)
        self.new_num = True

    def operation(self, op):
        if self.op_pending == True:
            self.do_sum()
            self.op = op
        else:
            self.op_pending = True
            if self.eq_flag == False:
                self.total = float(text_box.get())
            else:
                self.total = self.current
            self.new_num = True
            self.op = op
            self.eq_flag = False

    def cancel(self):
        text_box.delete(0, END)
        text_box.insert(0, "0")
        self.new_num = True

    def all_cancel(self):
        self.cancel()
        self.total = 0

    def sign(self):
        self.current = -(float(text_box.get()))
        text_box.delete(0, END)
        text_box.insert(0, self.current)

class My_Btn(Button):
    def btn_cmd(self, num):
        self["command"] = lambda: sum1.num_press(num)

sum1 = Calc()
root = Tk()
calc = Frame(root)
calc.grid()

root.title("Calculator")
text_box = Entry(calc, justify=RIGHT)
text_box.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 4, pady = 5, padx=5)
text_box.insert(0, "0")

#Buttons
numbers = "789456123"
i = 0
bttn = []
for j in range(2,5):
    for k in range(3):
        bttn.append(My_Btn(calc, text = numbers[i]))
        bttn[i].grid(row = j, column = k, pady = 5, padx=5)
        bttn[i].btn_cmd(numbers[i])
        i += 1
clear = Button(calc, text = "C", width =1, height =1)
clear["command"] = sum1.cancel
clear.grid(row = 1, column = 0, pady = 5, padx=5)

all_clear = Button(calc, text = "AC", width =1, height =1)
all_clear["command"] = sum1.all_cancel
all_clear.grid(row = 1, column = 1, pady = 5, padx=5)

bttn_div = Button(calc, text = chr(247))
bttn_div["command"] = lambda: sum1.operation("divide")
bttn_div.grid(row = 1, column = 2, pady = 5, padx=5)

bttn_mult = Button(calc, text = "x", width =1, height =1)
bttn_mult["command"] = lambda: sum1.operation("times")
bttn_mult.grid(row = 1, column = 3, pady = 5, padx=5)

minus = Button(calc, text = "-", width =1, height =1)
minus["command"] = lambda: sum1.operation("minus")
minus.grid(row = 2, column = 3, pady = 5, padx=5)

add = Button(calc, text = "+", width =1, height =1)
add["command"] = lambda: sum1.operation("add")
add.grid(row = 3, column = 3, pady = 5, padx=5)

neg= Button(calc, text = "+/-", width =1, height =1)
neg["command"] = sum1.sign
neg.grid(row = 4, column = 3, pady = 5, padx=5)

equals = Button(calc, text = "=", width =1, height =1)
equals["command"] = sum1.calc_total
equals.grid(row = 5, column = 3, pady = 5, padx=5)

point = Button(calc, text = ".", width =1, height =1)
point["command"] = lambda: sum1.num_press(".")
point.grid(row = 5, column = 2, pady = 5, padx=5)

bttn_0 = Button(calc, text = "0", width =7, height =1)
bttn_0["command"] = lambda: sum1.num_press(0)
bttn_0.grid(row=5, column = 0, columnspan = 2, pady = 5, padx=5)
```

Comment: Do you want to have the _option_ of pressing individual digit buttons (like most calculator apps), or do it only through keystrokes?

Comment: Like the calculator that comes with most operating systems. You can press the buttons or keystrokes.

Comment: OK, that's what I assumed, so I showed how to do that in my answer. (I assume you know how to do the layout, etc., so I kept that part as dead-simple and ugly as possible.)

Answer (score 2):

Rather than binding each key, I would use an Entry widget. People make mistakes. They'll want to hit the backspace key, or use the arrow keys or mouse to put the cursor someplace and edit what they've typed. You don't want to reinvent all that. If you give them an Entry widget, you get all that editing capability for free, and can parse the result when they press Enter.

```
entry.bind('<Enter>', parse)
```

Comment: You may want to use a validate method, to catch and reject any attempt to type anything that makes the result not a number, instead of parsing on Enter. But otherwise, agreed.

Comment: While you're right it would make it easier to input complex calculations, I'm fairly sure it would also turn into a nightmare trying to parse that entry box. You would need a fairly smart parser that could handle a very wide range of possible input, and that will translate into a fairly complex program. If OP wants to keep it simpler, I would strongly recommend against this approach.

Comment: @DaveTheScientist: All you need for a parser is `float` (and some error handling). Especially if you have a validate function—which is just a `try` around `float`—so there's no way the user can enter anything that can't be parsed (in which case you don't even need the error handling).

Comment: Yeah that'd be the easy part. Parsing the operations would be a lot harder I think, or at least more complicated. You'd need a case for every symbol they might type, and have to deal with everything in the correct order. Seems messy to me.

Comment: @DaveTheScientist: You could use Pyparsing to parse the expression safely. See for example, [fourFn.py](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/file/view/fourFn.py). Or, if you don't want to add that dependency, you could make a [top-down parser](http://effbot.org/zone/simple-top-down-parsing.htm).

Comment: Or you could compile the expression into AST and parse the tree. See [NumPy's SafeEval](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/lib/utils.py#L995) for example.

Comment: For this last option, you'd have to define some new methods, such as `SafeEval.visitCallFunc` to handle any math functions you want to allow, and also things like `SafeEval.visitAdd` and `SafeEval.visitSub` to define addition and subtraction, etc. But it can be done.

Answer (score 1):

I think the *right* way to do it is the way unutbu suggested, with an Entry. (You can use ttk theming if you want to make it not look like a normal Entry, and you can use focus tricks to make it work even when the user hasn't clicked on it.)

But if you *want* to do things your way, you can. Your `key` function can dispatch to functions that do the actual work (`append_digit` for digits, `backspace` for backspace/delete). Then, if you want buttons that do the same thing, you can add them, with callbacks that dispatch to the same functions. For example:

```
from functools import partial
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def key(event):
    print "pressed", repr(event.char)
    if event.char.isdigit():
        append_digit(event.char)
    elif event.char in ('\x08', '\x7f'):
        backspace()

def callback(event):
    frame.focus_set()
    print "clicked at", event.x, event.y

frame = Frame(root, width=100, height=100)
frame.bind("<Key>", key)
frame.bind("<Button-1>", callback)
frame.pack()

current = IntVar(0)
label = Label(frame, textvariable=current)
label.pack()

def button_callback(i):
    print "clicked button {}".format(i)
    append_digit(i)

def append_digit(digit):
    current.set(current.get() * 10 + int(digit))

def backspace():
    current.set(current.get() // 10)

for i in '1234567890':
    Button(frame, text=i, command=partial(button_callback, i)).pack()
Button(frame, text='C', command=backspace).pack()

frame.focus_set()
root.mainloop()
```

Obviously you can add more keystrokes and/or buttons—e.g., the "+" key and a button labeled "+" both trigger an add function, or a button labeled "AC" triggers a `current.set(0)` function, or whatever you want. And presumably you can design a nicer UI than a long column of buttons. This is just to show you the idea.